# .Stay on SSL across redirects

Tags: django, redirect, https

Parts of my site should be server over SSL. I'm only using paths (not full URLs) in links so users stay on SSL when opening links. However, when I use the redirect shortcut function the user is redirected to a non-SSL URL.

Is there any way to specify that the redirect should happen over SSL? It would be best if redirects behaved just like ordinary links and didn't change between HTTP and HTTPS protocols.

Comment: I haven't noticed this problem with my site, but that might be because I have the apache (running WSGI) setup to force all links to SSL.  Is that a viable workaround?

Answer (score 1):

What about the generic way for redirection? This couldn't work?

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('',   
    (r'^one/$', redirect_to, {'url': '/another/'}),

    #etc...
)
```

Also you can use the simplest way:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def myview(request):
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/path/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to come back on this old post but I've got exactly the same problem.
When I'm go on my swbsite (https://jib.li) over ssl, it redirects it to /home but without ssl...
I'm doing my redirect as suggested:

```
    url(r'^$', redirect_to, {'url': '/home/'})
```

Thanks!